# Prevent or detect screen recordings with audio in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, security, screen-recording

I want to protect an app against any kind of recordings possible, may it be screenshots or screen-recordings. I know I can use the library flutter_windowmanager to set a flag preventing screenshots and making the screen-recordings show a black screen, but audio can still be captured anyway, and I want to prevent this to.

Is there any way to do this? Preventing screen-recordings or recording nothing at all both are good enough solutions.

I have tried using several options, for example the libraries audio_session and screen_capture_event, and the class WidgetsBindingObserver, all without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [screen_protector](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector). and turn it on and off as below. it will avoid your app screen recording or taking screenshots

```
 void _preventScreenshotOn() async =>
      await ScreenProtector.preventScreenshotOn();
 void _preventScreenshotOff() async =>
      await ScreenProtector.preventScreenshotOff();
```

Comment: This solution may work for preventing screenshots, but as far as I know, it doesn't solve the issue about detecting the screen recording or preventing it from recording the app audio. It seems that it has a way to detect screen recording, but it's iOS only. Do you know if I can do something similar for Android to?